# Entity Framework and mapping relationships: What's the point?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

When I am working in SQL Management Studio I am accustomed to mapping relationships quite often (usually one-to-many).  Generally I do this to create various custom Views to help me optimize and otherwise formulate table outputs etc.  So i understand and see the value of defining relationships within tables of an SQL database.

Now I am getting into Entity Framework (moving from Linq2SQL). Primarily using SQL database driven model designer.  And I see how to map relationships in the EF designer.  Not too hard. But my question is...SO WHAT?

Let's say I map the two tables 'Invoice' to 'InvoiceItems' (one to many) in the EF designer.  How does this help me?  Why not map the relationship on the SQL server and import the view to do whatever it is that I want to do? Does it help with formulating LINQ queries?  If i delete an invoice record from 'Invoices' does EF automatically delete the child records in 'InvoiceItems'?

I am pretty jazzed to by utilizing EF, but I am not understanding the significance of relationship mapping within the EF designer.  Thanks for any clarification here.

Answer (score 3):

> How does this help me?

It helps by adding navigation properties to your entities so you do not have to constantly join two entities - so your code looks like:

```
foreach(InvoiceItem item in invoice.ItemDetails)
```

instead of

```
foreach(InvoiceItem item in db.InvoiceItems.Where(ii => ii.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID))
```

> Why not map the relationship on the SQL server and import the view to do whatever it is that I want to do?

You certainly can if you do database-first design.  EF will automatically create navigation properties that reflect the relationships in your database.

> If i delete an invoice record from 'Invoices' does EF automatically delete the child records in 'InvoiceItems'?

No, but if your database cascades deletes then they will be deleted when the parent is deleted.  Otherwise you'll need to intentionally delete child items.  If you are doing code-first development that you can use the Fluent API to add cascading deletes to the EF model.

Comment: ah ok ok. Many thx. 'foreach(InvoiceItem item in invoice.ItemDetails).'  That is a very helpful shorthand.  I seem to be stuck in a "database first" approach.

Comment: Which is fine if you're more comfortable designing the database then fitting an object model on top of it; some like to be able to define the object model the way they want it and then add custom code to generate the database effectively.  One way is not better or more "right" than the other.